# ffmpeg/probe cant open process manifest

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

Can anyone explain why ffmpeg/ffprobe can not load this manifest url:

https://q-hss-skylive-degn.akamaized.net/244431/stream.isml/Manifest?quality=hss5_dd

ffprobe returns:

```
Invalid data found when processing input
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello, you should provide the command(s) that you're using.

Comment: @Destroy666 `ffprobe https://q-hss-skylive-degn.akamaized.net/244431/stream.isml/Manifest?quality=hss5_dd`

Comment: Are you sure that stream is correct? In VLC it displays a bunch of "nonsense" which doesn't look intended.

Comment: Yes the stream is encrypted, that is why it doesn't look correct. I know how to decrypt streams using `-cenc_decryption_key`. But first I need to figure out why ffmpeg cant read/load it.

Comment: ffmpeg doesn't support reading ISML